# SQLAlchemy eager load specific subtype collection

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this (simplified) user / group model in one of my projects:

```
import sqlalchemy
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative
import sqlalchemy.orm
import sqlalchemy.schema

Base = sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base()


class Party(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Party'
    type = sqlalchemy.Column(
        sqlalchemy.String(1),
        nullable=False,
    )
    name = sqlalchemy.Column(
        sqlalchemy.String(255),
        primary_key=True,
    )

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'S',
        'polymorphic_on': type,
    }


class User(Party):
    __tablename__ = 'User'
    name = sqlalchemy.Column(
        sqlalchemy.String(255),
        sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKey(Party.name),
        primary_key=True,
    )

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'U',
    }


class Group(Party):
    __tablename__ = 'User'
    name = sqlalchemy.Column(
        sqlalchemy.String(255),
        sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKey(Party.name),
        primary_key=True,
    )

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'G',
    }


class UserGroup(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'UserGroup'
    user_name = sqlalchemy.Column(
        sqlalchemy.String(255),
        sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKey(User.name),
        primary_key=True,
    )
    group_name = sqlalchemy.Column(
        sqlalchemy.String(255),
        sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKey(Group.name),
        primary_key=True,
    )

    user = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship(User, backref='user_groups')
```

I encounter a problem when trying eager load the `user_groups` property of `User` in a polymorphic query:

```
party_poly = sqlalchemy.orm.with_polymorphic(Party, [User, Group])
results = session.query(party_poly) \
    .options(sqlalchemy.orm.subqueryload(User.user_groups)) \
    .all()
```

The error given is:

> Can't find property 'user_groups' on any entity specified in this Query.
>   Note the full path from root (Mapper|Party|Party) to target entity must be specified.

Through trial and error I got this query to work by changing

```
party_poly = sqlalchemy.orm.with_polymorphic(Party, [User, Group])
```

to

```
party_poly = sqlalchemy.orm.with_polymorphic(Party, [User, Group],
                                             _use_mapper_path=True)
```

So the question is; is it safe to rely on the undocumented, private argument `_use_mapper_path` argument?  Does anyone know what it does?

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?  If there is I'd like to hear it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_use_mapper_path` causes the `AliasedClass` generated to generate the entire mapper.  Without it, the `AliasedClass` will only generate its own class definition (and thus not contain the backref to `user_groups`).

I prefer to include the backrefs explicitly.  For example:

```
class A (db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'a'

    something = db.Column( db.BigInteger( unsigned=True ), primary_key=True )

    b         = db.relationship( 'B', use_list=False )

class B (db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'b'

    a_id      = db.Column( db.BigInteger( unsigned=True ), db.ForeignKey( 'a.id' ), primary_key=True )

    a         = db.relationship( 'A' )
```

This avoids the confusion of not having some commonly-used attributes of the class in the class definition and leads to significantly fewer mapper errors since it forces you to specify that a relation exists.

Comment: I tried using explicit relationships, however I get the same mapper error.  As a side note I prefer using the `backref` method as it allows me to pass the class to relationship instead of a string, e.g. `relationship(A, backref='b')` instead of `relationship('A')` - I don't know why it just seems more legit

Comment: Well...either way, `_use_mapper_path` is perfectly fine.